# Use jquery done on "non-ajax" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Can I use jquery `done()` on "non-ajax" functions. I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined` when I try to do something like this.

```
function countThreeSeconds() {
    var counter = 0,
    timer = setInterval(function () {

        if (counter == 3) {
            console.log("All done. That was three seconds.");
            window.clearInterval(timer);

        } else {
          console.log("Not there yet. Counter at: " + counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }, 1000);

}

(function(){
  var timer = countThreeSeconds().done(function(){
     alert("done");
  });

}());
```

Thanks

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/enesin/1/edit)

Comment: As you can see, you can't. jQuery has nothing to do with it. You can never call a method on `undefined`. jQuery methods don't just magically appear everywhere *(thank goodness)*. You can call them on specific objects defined in the jQuery library and as described by jQuery's API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make the non-ajax function return a promise object.

```
function countThreeSeconds() {
    var counter = 0,
    deferred = $.Deferred(),
    timer = setInterval(function () {

        if (counter == 3) {
            console.log("All done. That was three seconds.");
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            deferred.resolve();

        } else {              
            console.log("Not there yet. Counter at: " + counter);
            deferred.notify(counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise();

}

(function(){
  var timer = countThreeSeconds().done(function(){
     alert("done");
  }).progress(function(i){
     console.log("in progress...",i);
  });

}());
```

Comment: This is really nice. And makes perfect sense. So obvious now that I couldn't expect a normal function to automatically have access to all those deferred methods like jquery ajax. Thanks much!

Comment: `console.log()` accepts an infinite( i think? ) number of arguments, it just allows you to log more than one thing, or label each log so that you know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not returning anything from the function, it's perfectly valid JS behavior. To be able to use `done` on the function, return [`jQuery.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object from it.

Something like this:

```
function countThreeSeconds() {
    var defer = $.Deferred(function() { // do your stuff here });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a function to `$.Deferred`?  That's *not* where your code goes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat There's nothing wrong with doing it in the function. http://pastebin.com/CWXWcmkS

Comment: @KevinB: I just looked at the docs.  Guess you're right, but I've *never* seen it done that way.

Comment: @KevinB: Whoah!  I like that syntax. :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Me too. It's just usually easier to sprinkle it into existing code using the syntax i used in my answer.

Comment: @KevinB: The way in your answer is usually how I do it.  Actually, in the tutorial I read, I saw `deferred = new $.Deferred` instead, so I didn't know about passing a function to the constructor. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, with something like this, you could make a Deferred object (and its promise) really work for you.

For example, you could make `countThreeSeconds()` a raw, more generalized function, and have all progress/done reporting performed in the calling function.

```
function countSeconds(n) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred(),
        counter = 0,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            counter++;
            if (counter < n) { dfrd.notify(counter); }
            else { dfrd.resolve(); }
        }, 1000);
    return {
        promise: dfrd.promise(),
        timer: timer
    };
}

(function() {
    var timerObj = countSeconds(3);
    timerObj.promise.progress(function(counter) {
        console.log("Not there yet. Counter at: " + counter);
    }).done(function() {
        clearInterval(timerObj.timer);
        console.log("All done. That was three seconds.");
        alert("done");
    });
}());
```

Thus, another function could call `countSeconds()` with a different value, and handle progress and done situations differently.

For example :

```
(function() {
    var timerObj = countSeconds(10);
    timerObj.promise.progress(function(counter) {
        $("#message").text("Counter = " + counter);
    }).done(function() {
        clearInterval(timerObj.timer);
        $("#message").text('Complete');
    });
}());
```